# Multiple array add in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I want to add multiple array in autocomplete. I have added `aTags` but how can I add `bTags`?

```js
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];

var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];


$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: aTags,
  response: function(e, result) {
    if (!result.content.length) {
      console.log('No matches!');
      jQuery('#messag').html("Not match...").show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#messag').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
<span id="messag"></span>
```

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Sakib00123/jjc05c4h/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function to achieve this.

You would need to change the `source: aTags` to `source: aTags.concat(bTags)`

```js
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];

var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];


$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: aTags.concat(bTags),
  response: function(e, result) {
    if (!result.content.length) {
      console.log('No matches!');
      jQuery('#messag').html("Not match...").show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#messag').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='tags' />
<span id="messag"></span>
```